# vim search multiple pattern with either this or that

Tags: search, design-patterns, vim

I couldn't quite find help for this in forum w.r.t. vim search.

I'm looking to search for "abc.*(pqrs or xyz), that is I want abc with pqrs OR abc with xyz

/patternA.*(patternX|patternY)

I tried escaping "(" and "|", it didn't work. That is

/patternA.*(patternX\|patternY) also tried

/patternA.*(patternX\|patternY)

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 5):

```
/patternA.*\(patternX\|patternY\)
```

Comment: Or /\vpatternA.*(patternX|patternY)

Comment: I was searching for a pattern, data transferred (actual or expected). escaping bracket seem to work now, not why it didn't work then. Thanks **Magnus/yolenoyer**

Comment: @Nalan Periasamy, you seem to be used to perl-regex's. Vim's default is incompatible to that, but it adds the 'very magic' flag `\v`, the one yolenoyer used above. This makes vim almost compatible to perl. Look up `:help magic` as a starting point.